# jQuery - My slideToggle is laggy

Tags: jquery

Im creating this jquery action, but it is laggy at the slideDown, not on the slideUp of the SLideToggle action. How come this is happening? I am having other slideToggle's which is perfectly smooth.

```
$('.getGoingBtn').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.getGoingDesc').slideToggle();
});
```

On this HTML:

```
<ul>
        <li class='getGoingBtn'>Udfyld din profil</li>
            <li class='getGoingDesc'>En udfyldt profil er et trin på trappen over troværdigheden mellem mennesker på internettet. Derfor råder vi til, at du udfylder din profil med det samme (Kontrolpanel &raquo; Indstillinger)</li>
        <li class='getGoingBtn'>Opret dig som udbyder</li>
            <li class='getGoingDesc'>Her skal der være en beskrivelse</li>
</ul>
```

With this CSS:

```
.sideBarContent li.getGoingDesc{
        display:none;
        background:#fff;
        margin:0px 0 1px 3.5%;
        width:97%;
        border-top:0 solid #c3c3c3;
    }
```

*** This only happens when theres text inside ***

Comment: seems ok to me - http://jsfiddle.net/VErV5/

Comment: Not laggy for me: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HUWYz/)

Comment: it is very laggy for me. It is just at the middle of the animation of slideDown.. Then it's just jumping to the end o.O

Comment: Since we are unable to see the laggy project, we will have a hard time finding whats wrong with it. Presumably there is something someplace else mucking things up.

Comment: It's weird, cus' where ever I add  this UL on the page, it's doing the same.

Comment: @Dutchie432 If I create a height for the animated item, It's not laggy for me.. How come?

Comment: Perhaps the lag you are seeing is the resizing/reformatting of the contained content. Giving the content (or the container) a fixed size allows jquery to plan the content's layout in advance rather than shuffling things around as it expands.

Comment: Well, It's working now :-) Please throw an answer, you'll get the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing top and bottom borders, margins and paddings on the animated element,
as these are animated seperate.

I don't see any Problems with your code in general.